# Phoenix.Template.UndefinedError at GET /api/todos Could not render "index.json"

Tags: phoenix-framework

## Problem

**localhost:4000/api/todos** shows an error

> Phoenix.Template.UndefinedError at GET /api/todos
> Could not render "index.json"

### Code

**todo_view.ex**

```erl
defmodule TodoApiWeb.TodoView do
  use TodoApiWeb, :view
  alias TodoApiWeb.TodoView

  def render('index.json', %{todos: todos}) do
    render_many(todos, TodoView, "todo.json")
  end

  def render('todo.json', %{todo: todo}) do
    %{
      id: todo.id,
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the above issue convert the single quotes to double quotes.
Reload the **localhost:4000/api/todos** to see the json correctly load.